# Docker setup but apache on local machine

Tags: docker, apache, docker-compose

I have a docker setup (php7,mysql and apache). This is working correctly.

However, I have to transfer the project on the server where there is already an apache running.

I was wondering how I could use the apache on the server to connect to my docker setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `docker-compose` or `Dockerfile`, or combination of both to use together.

You can read more about them in **[Docker Compose Docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)** and **[Dockerfile Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)**.

**In Simple Answer**:

Create a `docker-compose.yml` file with contents you need as per above docs with a `Dockerfile`.

You should connect them together in your code by modifying files, like instead of `localhost` for database host, you should change it to the name you specify in `docker-compose.yml` file.

Also copying or adding some files in `apache`, like `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and `/etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf` (all files ending with `conf`), and for `mysql` like `/var/lib/mysql/` directory (database files), and of course your project files.

Then run `docker-compose up -d` command.